# Lump sum income grant is better than a subsidy grant

Tags: microeconomics, consumer-theory, choice-theory

There is an exercise in a Microeconomics book that says an income grant to a person provides more utility than does a subsidy on one good that costs the same amount to the government. Something like [this](https://www.economicsdiscussion.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/image_thumb109.png) gives a rough idea but not the complete picture. If I don't know the consumer's utility function, how can I reach a conclusion?

In other words, we have to show that $V(p_x, p_y, I+i_g) > V(p_x - s_g, p_y, I)$ where $s_g$ is set appropriately to ensure the government subsidizes the first good only so much that the subsidy (in unit currency) is $i_g$.

Comment: Hello! I don't know how this site works, can anyone tell me how to bring up my post so others can see it? ^_^

Comment: Your claim is the symmetric case of Example 3.1.1 in MWG, where a detailed proof is available.

Comment: @HerrK. I think it is 3.I.1. I found it in the book you suggested. Thank you.